# An isometry $A$ is unitarily equivalent to a shift $B$ iff. there is a space $L \subset H$ such that $A^n H \perp A^m H$ and $H = \bigoplus A^n L$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I honestly don't know how to prove it from $\Rightarrow$

I've spent the last couple of hours trying to figure it out, but I just don't see a way to prove it here. It's only true if we were to take $B^n H \perp B^m H$, and not $A$. Then it's pretty much straight forward as $B$ is a shift. But we need to take $A$ here, and as it's just unitarily equivalent to $A$, I don't think it's necessary true.

My proof for $\Leftarrow$:

$$K_n = B^n L$$

$$U_n : K_n \ni x \rightarrow Bx \in K_{n+1}$$

We get a bijection from $K_n$ to $L$ with $W_{n-1}$:

$$W_{n-1} = (U_{n-1} \circ \ldots \circ U_0)^{-1}$$

If we take

$$W = \bigoplus_{j=0}^{\infty} W_j$$

then this is a bijection from $H$ to $\ell^2_H (\mathbb{Z}_+)$, which shows that $BW = WA$

Comment: Is there a precise definition of "shift" you are working with?

Comment: @s.harp $A \{ x_0, x_1, ... \} = \{ 0, x_0, x_1, ... \}$

Comment: So there is a Hilbert basis on which it acts like the shift on $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$? The condition on the right permits also direct sums of such operators.

Comment: This is the Wold decomposition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_decomposition